# Kohana 3.2 ORM PDO: "The property id does not exist" on Model. Bug?

Tags: php, orm, kohana

When connected to a SQLite Database via PDO in Kohana I keep getting the following error:

> The property id does not exist in Model_Container.

The column exists in the database though.

When setting the $id as a public property on the Model the error disappears and everything works fine (also working like a charm on a MySQL Database).

any Ideas?

Thanks for the quick answer!

To clarify:
My Model looks somewhat like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Model_Container extends Model_App_Base {

    protected $_table_name = 'containers';

    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'active' => 'BOOL DEFAULT 1',
        'sorting_id' => 'INT(255)',
        'uid' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
        'name' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
        'area' => 'VARCHAR(50)'
    );

}
```

A routine in Model_App_Base creates the needed table and adds "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT"

when I extend my Model with the property that causes the error:

```
public $id;
```

it works as expected, though I wouldn't like to have them declared double times!

I'll try some stuff, maybe I'll figure out myself!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the column names on the model. PDO cannot get column names on it's own. I think you want http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#property:_table_columns

Comment: Your question looked very different when I answered ;)

Comment: Yeah, though you answerred perfectly right! Thank you, saved me a lot of headaches